# Angular 5 - Error getting data from local JSON file [object Object]

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I'm trying to get data from sampledata.json

**Errors:**

1. `{{sampledata}}` displaying `[object Object]`
2. `{{sampleDataModel.Title}}` ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Title' of undefined

**sampledata.json:**

```
  {
    "isSuccessfull": true,
    "Model": [
        {
            "SampleDataModel": [ 
                {
                  "Title": "SampleData 1",
                  "Description": "Description."
                }
            ],

            "SampleDetailModel": [
            {
                "name": "Donald Trump",
                "id": "111",
                "country": "USA"
            }
           ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

**sampledata.services.ts :**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


    @Injectable()
    export class SampledataService {

      private _url = 'assets/data/sampledata.json'

      constructor(private _http: Http) { }

      getData(){

        return this._http.get(this._url)
          .map((resSampleData: Response) => resSampleData.json());
      }

    }
```

**sampledata.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SampledataService } from '../sampledata.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sampledata',
  templateUrl: './sampledata.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sampledata.component.css']
})
export class SampledataComponent implements OnInit {

  sampledata = [];
  sampleDataModel = [];
  sampleDetailModel = [];

  constructor(private _sampledataservice: SampledataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {  

    this._sampledataservice.getData()
      .subscribe(resData => { 
        this.sampledata = resData;
        this.sampleDataModel = resData.Model.SampleDataModel;
        this.sampleDetailModel = resData.Model.SampleDetailModel });

  }

}
```

**sampledata.component.html:**

```
<h3>{{sampledata}}</h3>
<p>{{sampleDataModel.Title}}</p>
<p>{{sampleDetailModel.name}}</p>
```

**My Questions is:**

How do I get these values to display?

If anyone of you have any idea on how to solve this issue, please help to suggest the solutions to me, thank you.

Comment: try console.log on whole object. you will see sampledata.json has Model array( not Object) and in that array SampleDataModel and SampleDetailModel is also arrays not object.

Comment: Yes how do i convert it to object?

Comment: by using *ngFor loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<h3>{{sampledata | json}}</h3> // pipe | json needed to show object as stringyfied
<p>{{sampleDataModel[0]?.Title}}</p> // ? to check if object is not null or undefined
<p>{{sampleDetailModel[0]?.name}}</p>
```

And change like below

```
this.sampledata = resData;
this.sampleDataModel = resData.Model[0].SampleDataModel;
this.sampleDetailModel = resData.Model[0].SampleDetailModel
```

Comment: {{sampledata |json}} worked. Thanks. Is there a better way other than adding "|json" on html?                                                  
                                     
<p>{{sampleDataModel?.Title}}</p>
<p>{{sampleDetailModel?.name}}</p> didn't work

Comment: display properties one by one

Comment: Now I get "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined". Also how I stringyfy in service.ts or in component?

Comment: first try with `<pre>{{sampleDataModel| json}}</pre>` & `<pre>{{sampleDetailModel| json}}</pre>`

Comment: It did only display "&". No console errors @vinayakj

Comment: ahh got it.. your "Model" is also array.. check updated answer

Comment: Yes Model, SampleDataModel, SampleDetailModel are array. how do I convert then to object. Not in .json file

Comment: If not in .json file then why care, just access it using [index], no need to convert

Comment: Thank you. This worked. one last question. Is it good to use Model[0] or sampleDataModel[0] ? I might add few more data later

Comment: yes & no.. yes you can keep it as array but no need to access using index If you want to print them alluse *ngFor

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should try this:
in ngOnInit when getting back your data:

```
this._sampledataservice.getData()
    .subscribe(resData => { 
    this.sampledata = resData;
    this.sampleDataModel = resData.Model[0].SampleDataModel;
    this.sampleDetailModel = resData.Model[0].SampleDetailModel });
```

... and in HTML:

```
<h3>{{sampledata}}</h3>
<p>{{sampleDataModel[0].Title}}</p>
<p>{{sampleDetailModel[0].name}}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. one last question. Is it good to use Model[0] or sampleDataModel[0] ? I might add few more data later

Comment: What i usually do is make a strongly typed model, map it with data from server and bind it to the view and allways tryin to not use [0] or anything like that directly in html. Hope it helps.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

**Few observations as per the code in OP :**

1. > Access SampleDataModel

   To access `SampleDataModel` property, It should be `resData.Model[0].SampleDataModel` instead of `resData.Model.SampleDataModel`.
2. > {{sampleDataModel.Title}} ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property
   >   'Title' of undefined

   To access `Title` property of a `SampleDataModel` array. It should be `{{sampleDataModel[0].Title}}` instead of `{{sampleDataModel.Title}}`.

   ```
   this.sampleDataModel = resData.Model[0].SampleDataModel;
   ```
3. > {{sampledata}} displaying [object Object]

   As `sampledata` is a JSON object it is displaying as `[object object]`. `Stringify` it before use in the template.

   ```
   this.sampledata = JSON.stringify(resData);
   ```